# Need my JFileChooser for Mp3 data

Tags: java, filter, mp3, jfilechooser, filechooser

Im trying to create my own Mp3 Player ...

it is difficult for me to write an Jfile Chooser with Filter for Mp3

i have wrote my methode right in the GuiClas

```
       public void FileChooser()
{         
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

}
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) (you did read the docs, right?)

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "MP3 files", "mp3");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
```